# Update bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a grid with squares (tiles). Each of them has a color. Player1 = black, Player2 = white, no player = Transparant and if their is a square with no player but it is a valid move, the square has the color SkyBlue.

I have the code on pastebin because it is a lot.

TileviewModel: http://pastebin.com/b9kbuN5d
This is the viewmodel for each individual tile.

PlayerToColorTileConvertor: http://pastebin.com/1HXu083Q
I use a convertor to convert String words from viewmodel to Colors for the UI.

ReversiBoard: http://pastebin.com/fHdCEB9k
This is the xaml code.

Problem: I have a grid with 64 of these tiles. They each have a color like I said above. When I click on a SkyBlue button (eclipse in xaml code), normally some tile colors should change. The code is working great but the visual color update is not comming trought.

Is there an easy solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` needs to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the bindings.

You can raise the `PropertyChanged` event using a method like this:

```
protected void raisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Call this method with the property name as string every time the property changes.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not getting it done right. Could you make an example based on my code?
The best I could come up with: change the colors on the tiles, but 1 round to late. So they were updated, but they were off by one click. To make it clear, if I om at round 4, the SkyBlue colors were showed like it would be round 3.
Thanks.

Comment: update the question with the code you have now and make it clear where you update the tiles, then I can help you. Posting your whole uncommented viewmodel makes it very difficult for others to find out where exactly the mistake is

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and effort, you helped me out and provided another way of thinking.
I found the solution to my problem. In my xaml, I needed to get the value of the property. The property `ColorCell` returns an `ICell<String>`. So to get the value I only had to do: `Color="{Binding ColorCell.Value}"`.